# Custom USSD Menu depending on the telephone number?

Tags: dynamic, menu, ussd

I'm very new to USSD applications. I have a general question. Is it possible to create menus depending on the mobile phone using the USSD application? For example for number 000000001 construct menu A and show it, for number 000000002 construct and show menu B.

Comment: Yes, it's possible with RestComm. See http://www.telestax.com/creating-an-ussd-app-with-restcomm-visual-designer/ as well as http://www.telestax.com/building-ussd-apps-restcomm-part-1/ and http://www.telestax.com/building-ussd-apps-restcomm-part-2/. Feel free to get in touch if you need more help

Comment: @jeand I read the links you provided, it is really powerful tool! I have a question for you. For the USSD push messages, will the thread wait for response from subscriber side once the the message pushed?  Is it asynchronous or asynchronous  for such push transaction?Thanks

Comment: Thanks. feel free to upvote the answer then if you find useful for others in the future. It's asynchronous.